# JavaFX JavaScript upcall with arguments

Tags: java, javascript, arguments, javafx

I need to know how to up-call from JavaScript to JavaFX with arguments. Some sample code:

```
JSObject script = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
script.setMember("app", SignIn(arg1, arg2));

private boolean SignIn(String uid, String passwd) {
        boolean signedIn = false;
        System.out.println("Signing In");
        return signedIn;
}
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
<a onclick="app.SignIn(uid, passwd)">Click to sign in</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not work.

Comment: I have searched all over for the answer to this question. I have googled it, searched stackoverflow, and I have read through oracle tutorials, so I have done research. As for being clear I don't know how to make it any clearer. I am going to some of my code to the question.

Comment: "This code does not work" Well, what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
script.setMember("app", SignIn(arg1, arg2));
```

seems to be wrong. Try

```
script.setMember("app", new SignInManager());
```

where SignInManager is a **class** containing your SignIn(String uid, String passwd) method. You can make an analogy on this line like:

```
app = new SignInManager();
```

then use it in javascript code

```
app.SignIn(uid, passwd)
```

on click event. So (as a reply to your comment below) you are actually passing parameters from javascript code to Java code here.

By convention the method names should be started with lower case as signIn(String uid, String passwd).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, but I must pass arguments in this line script.setMember("app", SignIn(arg1, arg2));. This line calls the method SignIn(String, String), so to remove the arguments in the call would be invalid. Maybe JavaFX does not support up-calls with arguments.